# Error while moving a change set

Tags: force.com, deployment, profile, change-set

I am getting a strange error while moving a custom app from my one sandbox to another. I have created some profiles with force.com free User license. When I am trying to move this profile which has access to only one custom app I get an error saying - "Can't complete this operation because it would exceed the number of apps allowed by the user license".

When I checked the profile setting I have only one app assigned to the profile since force.com free user license can only have access to one custom app.Here is a screen shot from the profile setting page:

[image]

Any idea what I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please look at this from Salesforce and see if it helps 
http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000220879

Comment: Can you post some relevant content from there? Link only answers aren't much use as they tend to break over time.

Comment: @SFDC_BigDog - I do not have any permission set. By the way I am moving profiles and not users/permission sets.

Comment: This profile is of force.com free user and I have given access to more than 10 objects for this profile. Is that the reason?